# Android Studio: Layout is going under the device buttons

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation

I'm writing an android app and have a problem with the user interface.

I have a chat section with the styling here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#efefef"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".FragmentChat"
android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android:height = "0dp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout" />
    <!--
    android:background="@null"
    android:divider="@null"
    -->


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Send" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However; when I try run the application in an emulator, bottom side of the view extends under the navigation buttons

[image: like this.]

However, what I want it to be is like this:

[image: this], as shown in the layout preview section of Android Studio.

I tried many iterations with different `layout_height` values for every member of the layout and even though the preview shows it proper, when actually run the EditView and Button are left under the nav buttons. Can you help me sort this out?

Edit: I located the problem. Since view is tabbed, `layout_height="match_parent"` puts the edittext and button to the bottommost point of the tallest tab fragments. Still can't find a solution though.

Comment: Just use a basic FrameLayout for root instead of RelativeLayout. Then set a static marginBottom to your list. Also make gravity bottom for LinearLayout. ListView isn't a reliable componenet for ui relations, because of dynamic height. In your code, ListView is overriding your LinearLayout.

Comment: Remove android:stackFromBottom="true" from your ListView.

Comment: Neither of those work sadly

Comment: I located the problem. Since view is tabbed, `layout_height="match_parent"` puts the edittext and button to the bottommost point of the tallest tab fragments. Still can't find a solution though.

Comment: @Waylander  I've had an app in service for 10 years, and it's worked on many devices. I've recently (2023) encountered this problem on one particular device. Curiously, on this device it works better than all others, apart from this one problem. This device has higher resolution and *more* space than the others! Glad to see your question! But, a little disappointed that after you tried several solutions you weren't able to publish one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I located the problem. Since view is tabbed, `layout_height="match_parent"` puts the edittext and button to the bottommost point of the tallest tab fragments. Still can't find a solution though.